# Does "you're bad" mean "you're good" in American English if the context is clear?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

> In [the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bad_1?q=bad), **bad** (comparative badder, superlative baddest)
> (especially North American English, slang) good; excellent

Say, your friend has just made a very beautiful dress. And when you look at it, can you say "**you're bad**" which means "**you're good**" in American English?

Does "**he is badder than me**" mean "**he is better than me**" in Ame English?

Some people say we have to say "**he is badder than I**". I am wondering why not "**he is badder than I am**"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with **He is better than I am**. Strictly speaking, **He is better than me** is incorrect, but it is very frequently used in casual speech.

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is (or was) use in some African American dialects, and particularly in relation to a musical or other performance. The OED gives this example:

> Bad as the best and as cool as they come, Smokey is remarkably low key for a soul master.

and has earlier citations:

> [Duke] Ellington’s jazzique is just too bad.

And there was, of course, Michael Jackson's album *Bad*.

But the main meaning of "bad" = "not good" remains the main meaning.  If an African American speaker uses the slang meaning they might be understood in context.  If a non-native speaker uses the slang meaning, there would just be confusion. So don't add this to your productive vocabulary.

Comment: Similarly gnarly, nasty, sick etc. Don't use these words unless in conversation with a teenager - but in conversation with a teenager again don't use them, because they will have stopped using them last week & now you look to be even older & more out of touch than before you started speaking ;)